# NullPointerException when populating ArrayAdapter with ArrayList in AsyncTask

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I initialize an ArrayList,

```
    ArrayList<Episode> episodes = new ArrayList<Episode>(32);
```

and then fill that list asynchronously by polling an RSS feed.

When the async call, `onPostExecute`s, I pass `populateList` with episodes:

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            populateList(episodes);
        }
```

Which passes the `ArrayList` into a custom `ArrayAdapter`, `EpisodeAdapter`.

```
    public void populateList(ArrayList<Episode> episodes) {
        episodeAdapter = new EpisodeAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.row_episodes, episodes);
        mList.setAdapter(episodeAdapter);
    }
```

Thanks to the new Crash reports, I'm starting to realize **just how often this results in `NullPointerExceptions`**... very often (however I cannot seem to reproduce it locally!).

Depending on the fix I'm using at the time, the stack trace looks something like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:234)
  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:178)
  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:163)
  at com.workingagenda.democracydroid.Adapters.EpisodeAdapter.<init>(EpisodeAdapter.java:47)
  at com.workingagenda.democracydroid.MainActivity$PodcastFragment.populateList(MainActivity.java:236)
  at com.workingagenda.democracydroid.MainActivity$PodcastFragment$GetAudioFeed.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:590)
  at com.workingagenda.democracydroid.MainActivity$PodcastFragment$GetAudioFeed.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:545)
```

I've tried many things to reduce the number of crashes, namely checking before I call `populateList`, that the ArrayList `episodes` `.size()` is not 0 (which is always I think because I initialize it to a length of 32). Or, inside `populateList` I check to see if the first item is `null` (like:

```
        if (episodes.get(0) != null){
            episodeAdapter = new EpisodeAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.row_episodes, episodes);
            mList.setAdapter(episodeAdapter);
        }
```

But then sometimes I get an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` (but sometimes still the `NullPointerException`.

How do I prevent the app from crashing if the episodes are for some reason not populated by the async call?

Should I be checking for null inside the Adapter's `getView()` method instead?

Does checking the first item for null not make any sense? Or should I check that *with* checking the `size()` of the ArrayList?

Comment: Yes checking first element not null will not make big difference first u can check arraylist not null than check arraylist size greater than 0 after this all u can check Episode model class not any null value before using those values

Comment: So I need to check three things, and where should I check them? I thought Arraylist would never be null, because I do init it?

Comment: I think that if you are using an Async task it is possible that your ListView is not being initialized in the correct order.

Comment: Please add all of the `EpisodeAdapter` class

Comment: If your AsyncTask may leave the "episodes" variable null in case of network error, then you need to check for it to be null first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's crashing when you make a new adapter...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:234)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:178)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:163)
    at com.workingagenda.democracydroid.Adapters.EpisodeAdapter.<init>(EpisodeAdapter.java:47)
```

Which is wrong way to update the data.

---

You need to clear the list, then repopulate, then notify.

I would also suggest that you return the new list from the `doInBackground`

```
@Override
protected void doInBackground(List<Episode> episodes) {
    List<Episode> newEpisodes = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        yourNetworkCallHere();
        newEpisodes.add(...);
    } catch (Exception e) {} 

    return newEpisodes;  // this can't be null 
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(List<Episode> results) {
    episodes.clear();
    episodes.addAll(results);
    episodeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If you get a network error, then you get an empty list, which isn't null.

If you get an out of bounds exception, that's a logical error elsewhere

Comment: I see, I'll give this a try soon soon and get back to you, thanks

Comment: Thank you! This helped me realize that I needed to rethink how I handled the allocation of new Objects

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Where is the best place to define         episodeAdapter = new EpisodeAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.row_episodes, episodes); ?

Comment: @user1090751 1) Personally, I say `onCreateView` (use a Fragment, not an Activity) 2) You should make a new post to ask this

Answer (score 0):

Check arraylist is NOT empty

```
 if (!episodes.isEmpty()){
        episodeAdapter = new EpisodeAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.row_episodes, episodes);
        mList.setAdapter(episodeAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. This does **not** work :) (already tried it)

Comment: check if (!episodes.isEmpty())

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting a null response in your `AsyncTask`. In which case when you assign that value to your `episodes` variable, it will become null and hence the `NullPointerException`.

Simply do a null check before updating the value of your `episodes` variable.

```
@Override
protected void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    List<Episode> newEpisodes = yourNetworkCallHere();
    if (newEpisodes != null) {
        episodes = newEpisodes;
    }
}
```

Comment: And you can always clear the arraylist if the response is null. If that's what you want.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you never will see the new data in the list with this approach. Go ahead and try